# Setting up `Ubuntu Monospace` font for a specific listing

Tags: fonts, listings, typewriter

- My OS : Ubuntu 13.10
- Latex version used : Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

In my report, I am using the following listing :

```
\lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=3pt,
  frame=tb,
  framerule=0pt,
  columns=fullflexible
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to configure the font style of this listing (and this listing only!), setting up`basicstyle`, I assume. I would like to configure this font style as `Ubuntu Monospace` (known by my OS).

Is there a simple way for doing it please ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the `fontspec` package to load fonts in XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use

```
\newfontfamily\UbuntuMonospace{Ubuntu Monospace}
```

in your preamble, and then, in your list of options for `listings`, include

```
basicstyle=\small\UbuntuMonospace
```

If this is the only use of monospaced fonts in your document, you can instead use

```
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Monospace}
```

in the preamble, which will then define `\texttt` to use Ubuntu Monospace. Thus using this in your listing will require simply

```
basicstyle=\small\texttt
```

Answer (score 3):

that is only possible with `XeLaTeX` or  `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\UMono[Scale=0.9]{UbuntuMono-Regular}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\UMono,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=3pt,
  frame=tb,
  framerule=0pt,
  columns=fullflexible
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=BashInputStyle]
rsync -tovupgilr --progress --delete --exclude-from=/extern.txt / /extern
\end{lstlisting}

%the same with the default mono font:
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]
rsync -tovupgilr --progress --delete --exclude-from=/extern.txt / /extern
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the used fonts in the pdf are:

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdffonts test7.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JLZYGL+LMRoman5-Regular              CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
UYSVMJ+UbuntuMono-Regular            CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
FXXUVH+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
PREOYV+LMMono9-Regular               CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
JFRMQG+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I suppose it means that I need to install textlive-full on my system then. There is no configuration possible on pdflatex if I understand you well? Why so?

Comment: I _always_ use TeXLive full from http://tug.org/texlive/ and not the one from Ubuntu. However, it is also possible to use the font with `pdflatex`, if you create all the needed auxiliary files which is not really simple.

Comment: How did you compiled this ? I do not manage to handle it using xelatex, since I am receiving some "Option `pdftex' requires pdfTeX" errors.

Comment: looks like that you have an optional argument `pdftex` in your preamble when loading a package, e.g. `graphicx`. Delete that option it is already not needed.